# After adding a hook client's not able to login WHMCS

Tags: php, whmcs

We are trying to modify our menu in WHMCS, But when we add a hook for this our client's not able to login in client area.
Please tell what we are doing wrong.

Here is our hook code

```
 <?php


 use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

 add_hook('ClientAreaNavbars', 1, function ()
 {
$primaryNavbar = Menu::primaryNavbar();
$primaryNavbar->removeChild('Contact Us');
$primaryNavbar->removeChild('Network Status');
$primaryNavbar->removeChild('Live-Help-Button');

$primaryNavbar->addChild('Free Shortcut')
        ->setUri('/cart.php?a=add&pid=2')
        ->setOrder(70);
// Moves a menu item to the last position
$primaryNavbar->getChild('Affiliates')->moveToBack();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code and gave the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function moveToBack() on null in my_hoos.php

Probably the Affiliates system is disabled, and the menu item wasn't there, and the $primaryNavbar->getChild('Affiliates') returns an empty value.

To fix it, replace:

```
$primaryNavbar->getChild('Affiliates')->moveToBack();
```

With:

```
$item = $primaryNavbar->getChild('Affiliates');

if ($item instanceof MenuItem) {
     $item->moveToBack();
}
```